# Http code 500 vs Http code 422 server crash scenario

Tags: http, httprequest, httpresponse

Suppose I have a client that makes a http request to Service A then Service A makes a http request to Service B but Service B is down and not accepting requests.  What should Service A return to the client?  Is a HTTP status code 422 the right response or a 5** error status.  The request is correct with no semantic errors.

Comment: 4xx denotes a client's fault. As it is probably not the client's fault if service B is down, I'd go with something like 503 - service unavailable